# What are the luggage storage options available in Porto?

Tags: portugal, luggage-storage, porto

I have a day to kill in Porto and a large suitcase I don't wish to haul around the city. Once I'm done touring I'll be heading for the airport. What are the luggage storage options available in Porto?

Comment: Considered googling it? (googles 'luggage storage options porto', writes an answer)

Comment: @MarkMayo I considered it but my roaming edge connection doesn't allow much googling. :)

Comment: Heh, I've added more info, had to do some translation from the company's website, but hopefully has even more useful tidbits now that you may accept it ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[From tripadvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.com.au/ShowTopic-g189180-i598-k5446075-Left_Luggage_Lockers_Porto_Trindade_metro_station-Porto_Porto_District_Northern_Portugal.html):

> lockers are now available in Porto downtown at Trindade metro station
>   - with direct connection to Porto Airport.
>
> The station is opened all the year from 06am to 01am, and the service
>   it's not expensive.

Another link to the [company site](http://www.citylockers.pt/PT/) shows more information.

Their FAQ is broken in English, but from my rough translation, it's not necessary to reserve, they're open from 6am to 1am, and the baggage dimensions for storage are:

- Small: 36x48x85 cm.
- Medium: 36x65x85 cm.
- Large: 36x99x85 cm.

The prices depend on how long and how large a locker you require, and are available [in pdf format](http://www.citylockers.pt/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Luggage-Lockers-Prices-list.pdf).  It varies between 1 Euro for 1 hour for a small bag up to 6 Euros for an all day storage of a large one.

At the time of writing there is just one block of lockers comprising 16 small lockers, 9 medium and 2 large, as shown in this picture (from the aforementioned company website):

[image: Luggage locker Trinidade station Porto]

If you are travelling with large suitcases you'll need to either find a free large locker or try to cram the suitcase in a medium one. Note that self-service luggage storage services being scarse in Porto, the lockers tend to be all occupied most of the time.

Comment: It's **not** the only one in Porto. There are similar lockers at São Bento train station.

Answer (score 2):

There is a new luggage storage facility in Porto: [The Cloakroom](https://www.facebook.com/search/top/?q=the%20biggest%20cloakroom).

It is located downtown, the address is Taipas Street, 59.

The phone number is 00 351 9389 21777

I have no other information about it though.